# update-alternatives has no effect on the /etc symlinks?

Tags: python, update-alternatives

I want `python3` and `python` to both point to the current `python3.10` . i can not get that to work for the life of me.  Here are the current commands

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python $(which python3.10) 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 $(which python3.10) 1
```

And here's the result

```
ls -lrta /etc/alternatives | grep python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Mar 23 16:26 python -> /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Mar 23 16:40 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.8
```

How is this supposed to work?

Note: this is in a single-use single-task `Docker` container with no gui involved, so I am  unconcerned with side-effects of marginalizing the system python. We do not need it, just python3.10

Comment: You've not said what OS/release you're using, but you'll discover many Ubuntu tools (esp. for desktop systems) will no longer function if the default python3 version is changed (*thus the protections you're likely coming up against*).  What OS/release are you using?

Comment: i am on `20.04` . it's a single-task container, i just need 3.10 working

Comment: Please add additional details to your question, and also be complete; ie. 20.04 Server has lesser effects than 20.04 Desktop for example, but you've not said which 20.04 product.. Changing the default python3 may prevent future logins on a desktop system for example; loss of `gnome-terminal` etc...  but won't impact text logins (ie. server) etc.

Comment: @guiverc  I did not add them because they're not necessarily relevant: I am only interested in mechanically how to make `update-alternatives` choose the `python3.10`.  Any of the other system related fallouts/side-effects I already understand and am unconcerned.  I'll add the details anyways .

Comment: 1 is probably the lowest priority (or maybe 0). Either set a higher priority value, or switch from auto to manual mode.

Comment: (slap forehead) i was thinking 1 were highest priority

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 ships with python 3.8. Changing the default version will mess the OS most likely beyond repair. Ubuntu needs to run only the exact version it ships with. Ubuntu 22.04 ships with 3.10

Comment: > Ubuntu 22.04   .   That will have internal company support in about 2025